# WPF SystemColors.HighlightTextBrushKey IsFrozen=True; How to change Foreground of Selected Item on ListBox Control

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, wpf-controls

I have this Xaml

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}"
    Value="#123456"/>        
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightTextBrushKey}" 
    Value="White"/>
```

THe first one works, the second one does not. On MSDN, SystemColors.HighlightTextBrushKey says that it "IsFrozen" and cannot be changed, so I tried this in my style:

```
<Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="true">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
</Trigger>
```

Which also does not work, any guidance would be really helpful, thanks.

**Edit** -- Additional Xaml

```
    <ListBox ItemContainerStyle="{DynamicResource ListBoxItemStyle}" 
        AlternationCount="2"
        Margin="8,37,8,74" 
        x:Name="listClientOUContents" 
        HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid Height="22" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                    <Image Margin="-2,0,0,0" Source="{Binding Path=ADsPath, Converter={StaticResource ImxConverter}}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="22"  />
                    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="20,3,0,0" Text="{Binding Path=DisplayValue}" />
                    <Rectangle HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Fill="White" Stroke="White" Margin="-2,0,-2,0.5" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Height="1" />
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

Here is the ItemContainerStyle I'm using

```
<Style x:Key="ListBoxItemStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="12" />
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Tahoma" />
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="#006C3B3B"/>
        <Style.Resources>
            <!-- Selected and Focused -->
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" Color="#FF533F70"/>
            <!-- Selected and UN-focused -->  
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}" Color="#FF533F70"/>
            <Storyboard x:Key="MouseOverStoryBoard">
                <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames AutoReverse="True" BeginTime="00:00:00" Storyboard.TargetName="{x:Null}" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)">
                    <SplineColorKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00" Value="#FFF48F21"/>
                    <SplineColorKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.5000000" Value="#FF4A475C"/>
                </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            </Storyboard>
        </Style.Resources>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="true">
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="ItemsControl.AlternationIndex" Value="0">
                <Setter Property="Background">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <SolidColorBrush Color="#a1a1a1"/>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="black"/>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="ItemsControl.AlternationIndex" Value="1">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="#a1a1a1"/>
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="black"/>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                <Trigger.EnterActions>
                    <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource MouseOverStoryBoard}"/>
                </Trigger.EnterActions>
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FFF48F21"/>
                <Setter Property="FontStyle" Value="Normal"/>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
```

Comment: Can you show more of your XAML (The ListBox element and all relevant elements contained in your list box)?

Comment: Yes... I've edited the question with more xaml.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: Switch the order of your 'IsSelected' trigger and your 'ItemsControl.AlternationIndex' trigger:

```
<Trigger Property="ItemsControl.AlternationIndex" Value="0">
    <Setter Property="Background">
        <Setter.Value>
            <SolidColorBrush Color="#a1a1a1"/>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="black"/>
</Trigger>
<Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="true">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
</Trigger>
```

The last trigger in the list is taking priority, so your AlternationIndex was overriding your IsSelected trigger. With IsSelected being listed after the AlternationIndex, it should now take priority.